# Pure JavaScript: How to refresh page after countdown if the browser tab is active

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve the following scenario:

> Set a timer of 60 seconds and start the countdown displaying the
> timer. After the countdown is finished, refresh (not reload) the page
> and restart the countdown timer and continue the process.
>
> If the browser's tab is changed, after finishing the timer, refresh the
> page and pause the timer, and only when the tab is active again refresh
> the page and start the countdown timer again.

I have managed to achieve the first requirement like:

```
Result will Refresh in <span id="countdown"></span>
<script>
  if (!document.hidden) {
    function timedRefresh(e) {
      var n = setInterval((function () {
        e > 0 ? (e -= 1, document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = e) : (clearInterval(n), window.location.reload())
      }), 1e3)
    }
    timedRefresh(59)
  }
</script>
```

And is unable to achieve the second requirement. I have tried to implement the solution mentioned here: [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)
But it didn't work.

**How do I achieve the requirements in pure JavaScript code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code has solved this scenario. It's a little messy, but I think is understandable. We use both `window.document.hasFocus()` and the focus event to create this solution. I have changed the `window.location.reload()` methods to just consoles simulating a function that refresh the data inside the application, since is asked to us *refresh (not reload)*.

```
    function timedRefresh(intervalTime) {
        let interval = null;
        let currentTime = intervalTime;

        const updateTimer = () => {
            const countdownSpan = document.getElementById("countdown");

            if (currentTime <= 0) {
                console.log(`print refresh at ${new Date()}`); // refresh page
                if (window.document.hasFocus()) {
                    currentTime = intervalTime;
                } else {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    interval = null;
                    currentTime = intervalTime;
                }
            }

            if (!interval) {
                countdownSpan.innerHTML = "#";
            } else {
                countdownSpan.innerHTML = currentTime;
                currentTime -= 1;
            }
        };

        interval = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
        window.addEventListener("focus", () => {
            if (!interval) {
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    const TIMER_SECONDS = 5;
    timedRefresh(TIMER_SECONDS);
```

**Edit:**

The answer above does not work with reloads using `window.location.realod()`. A code solving the issue may look like this:

```
  const TIMER_SECONDS = 60;

/* 
 * Update span with current time
 *  `currentTime` is an integer bigger than zero or a string '#' meaning 'timer stopped'
 */
function updateDisplayTimer(currentTime){
  const countdownSpan = document.getElementById("countdown");
  countdownSpan.innerHTML = currentTime;
}

/*
 * A timer with `loopDuration` seconds. After finished, the timer is cleared.
 *  `loopDuration` is an integer bigger than zero, representing the time duration in seconds.
 */
function timedRefresh(loopDuration) {

  let currentTime = loopDuration;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (currentTime > 0) {
      updateDisplayTimer(currentTime);
      currentTime -= 1;
    } else {
      window.location.reload(); // refresh page
    }
  }, 1000);

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if(window.document.hasFocus()){
      timedRefresh(TIMER_SECONDS);
    } else {
      updateDisplayTimer("#");
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    if(interval == null){
      window.location.reload(); // refresh page
    }
  });
}

// exeute main fucntion 
timedRefresh(TIMER_SECONDS);
```

Comment: The page keeps reloading even after the tab is changed. It should reload only once.

Comment: Have you switched the ```console.log(`print refresh at ${new Date()})`; // refresh page``` with `window.location.reload()`? If you do so, this code will not work properly. When the window has loaded, the function `timedRefresh` is called again, and the variables inside the function scope are cleared. Maybe I can find some answer to this case.

Comment: I did. Refreshing the page is the primary requirement.

Comment: What about now? I've edited the answer. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.document.hasFocus()` to determine if the user is focused on your webpage or not.

Comment: Can you post the logic of the second part in pure JS?

Comment: The function returns true if your window is focused. SO before starting your timer, check if window has focus, and if not, pause the timer.